# how to make Windows 7 have website access through VPN connection

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, openvpn, internet

I am still struggle with my Windows 7 VPN client’s internet access. My OpenVPN client-server works great for my Windows 10 laptop and my Android phones. But my Windows 7 laptop cannot gain internet access with the VPN connection.

Please note, it is just that I cannot access web sites. I can still send and receive email to and from my another account between different email vendors. The following are ”tracert” info, “route print” info, “Client Log” and “Client config” for you. Please help me. I have replaced some number with XXX.

I have added openVPN exception in the firewall.

```
C:\Users\l>tracert www.google.com
Unable to resolve target system name www.google.com.

C:\Users\l>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 32...00 ff f5 73 11 4c ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 28...ea 2a ea 22 78 66 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #6
 27...ea 2a ea 22 78 65 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #5
 26...e8 2a ea 22 78 65 ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
 22...00 ac 12 61 93 6b ......VPN Client Adapter - VPN
 13...54 ee 75 12 9c b9 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM
 31...0a 00 27 00 00 1f ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 35...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 19...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 37...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 33...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
 38...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #7
 36...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
 34...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #9
 30...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #11
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.1.10.1      10.1.10.114     25
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.2    276
        10.1.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       10.1.10.114    281
      10.1.10.114  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.10.114    281
      10.1.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.10.114    281
         10.8.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.8.0.2    276
         10.8.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.2    276
       10.8.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.2    276
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0         10.8.0.1         10.8.0.2    276
     192.168.56.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
     192.168.56.1  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
   192.168.56.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
    209.6.118.XXX  255.255.255.255        10.1.10.1      10.1.10.114    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       10.1.10.114    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.8.0.2    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.56.1    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.1.10.114    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.8.0.2    276
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 31    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 31    266 fe80::6500:253d:40e5:d358/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 31    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Client log:

```
    Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420 Current Parameter Settings:
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   config = 'client1.ovpn'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   mode = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   show_ciphers = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   show_digests = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   show_engines = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   genkey = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   key_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   show_tls_ciphers = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   connect_retry_max = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420 Connection profiles [0]:
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   proto = udp
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   local = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   local_port = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   remote = 'XXX.hopto.org'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   remote_port = '1194'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   remote_float = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   bind_defined = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   bind_local = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   bind_ipv6_only = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   connect_retry_seconds = 5
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   connect_timeout = 120
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   socks_proxy_server = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   socks_proxy_port = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   tun_mtu = 1500
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   tun_mtu_defined = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   link_mtu = 1500
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   link_mtu_defined = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   tun_mtu_extra = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   tun_mtu_extra_defined = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   mtu_discover_type = -1
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61420   fragment = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   mssfix = 1450
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   explicit_exit_notification = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920 Connection profiles END
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   remote_random = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ipchange = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   dev = 'tun'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   dev_type = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   dev_node = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   lladdr = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   topology = 1
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ifconfig_local = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ifconfig_remote_netmask = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ifconfig_noexec = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ifconfig_nowarn = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ifconfig_ipv6_local = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ifconfig_ipv6_netbits = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ifconfig_ipv6_remote = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   shaper = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   mtu_test = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   mlock = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   keepalive_ping = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   keepalive_timeout = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   inactivity_timeout = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ping_send_timeout = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ping_rec_timeout = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ping_rec_timeout_action = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   ping_timer_remote = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   remap_sigusr1 = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   persist_tun = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   persist_local_ip = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   persist_remote_ip = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   persist_key = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   passtos = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   resolve_retry_seconds = 1000000000
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   resolve_in_advance = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   username = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   groupname = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   chroot_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   cd_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   writepid = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   up_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   down_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   down_pre = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   up_restart = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   up_delay = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   daemon = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   inetd = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   log = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   suppress_timestamps = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   machine_readable_output = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   nice = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   verbosity = 4
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=61920   mute = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   gremlin = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   status_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   status_file_version = 1
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   status_file_update_freq = 60
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   occ = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   rcvbuf = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   sndbuf = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   sockflags = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   fast_io = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   comp.alg = 2
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   comp.flags = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   route_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   route_default_gateway = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   route_default_metric = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   route_noexec = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   route_delay = 5
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   route_delay_window = 30
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   route_delay_defined = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   route_nopull = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   route_gateway_via_dhcp = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   allow_pull_fqdn = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   [redirect_default_gateway local=0]
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   management_addr = '127.0.0.1'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   management_port = '25341'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   management_user_pass = 'stdin'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   management_log_history_cache = 250
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   management_echo_buffer_size = 100
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   management_write_peer_info_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   management_client_user = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   management_client_group = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   management_flags = 6
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   shared_secret_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   key_direction = not set
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   ciphername = 'AES-128-CBC'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   ncp_enabled = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   ncp_ciphers = 'AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   authname = 'SHA256'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   prng_hash = 'SHA1'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   prng_nonce_secret_len = 16
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   keysize = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   engine = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   replay = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   mute_replay_warnings = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   replay_window = 64
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   replay_time = 15
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   packet_id_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   use_iv = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   test_crypto = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   tls_server = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   tls_client = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   key_method = 2
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62420   ca_file = 'ca.crt'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   ca_path = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   dh_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   cert_file = 'client1.crt'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   extra_certs_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   priv_key_file = 'client1.key'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   pkcs12_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   cryptoapi_cert = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   cipher_list = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   tls_cert_profile = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   tls_verify = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   tls_export_cert = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   verify_x509_type = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   verify_x509_name = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   crl_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   ns_cert_type = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_ku[i] = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   remote_cert_eku = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   ssl_flags = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   tls_timeout = 2
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   renegotiate_bytes = -1
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   renegotiate_packets = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   renegotiate_seconds = 3600
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   handshake_window = 60
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   transition_window = 3600
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   single_session = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   push_peer_info = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   tls_exit = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   tls_auth_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   tls_crypt_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=62920   pkcs11_protected_authentication = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   pkcs11_private_mode = 00000000
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   pkcs11_cert_private = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   pkcs11_pin_cache_period = -1
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   pkcs11_id = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   pkcs11_id_management = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   server_network = 0.0.0.0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   server_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   server_network_ipv6 = ::
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   server_netbits_ipv6 = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   server_bridge_ip = 0.0.0.0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   server_bridge_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   server_bridge_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   server_bridge_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   ifconfig_pool_defined = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   ifconfig_pool_start = 0.0.0.0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63420   ifconfig_pool_end = 0.0.0.0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   ifconfig_pool_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   ifconfig_pool_persist_filename = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   ifconfig_pool_persist_refresh_freq = 600
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_defined = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_base = ::
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   ifconfig_ipv6_pool_netbits = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   n_bcast_buf = 256
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   tcp_queue_limit = 64
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   real_hash_size = 256
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   virtual_hash_size = 256
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   client_connect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   learn_address_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   client_disconnect_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   client_config_dir = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   ccd_exclusive = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   tmp_dir = 'C:\Users\l\AppData\Local\Temp\'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   push_ifconfig_defined = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   push_ifconfig_local = 0.0.0.0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   push_ifconfig_remote_netmask = 0.0.0.0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   push_ifconfig_ipv6_defined = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   push_ifconfig_ipv6_local = ::/0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   push_ifconfig_ipv6_remote = ::
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   enable_c2c = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   duplicate_cn = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   cf_max = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   cf_per = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   max_clients = 1024
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   max_routes_per_client = 256
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   auth_user_pass_verify_script = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   auth_user_pass_verify_script_via_file = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   auth_token_generate = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   auth_token_lifetime = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   client = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   pull = ENABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   auth_user_pass_file = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   show_net_up = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   route_method = 3
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   block_outside_dns = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   ip_win32_defined = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   ip_win32_type = 3
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   dhcp_masq_offset = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   dhcp_lease_time = 31536000
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   tap_sleep = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   dhcp_options = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   dhcp_renew = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   dhcp_pre_release = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   domain = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=63920   netbios_scope = '[UNDEF]'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=64420   netbios_node_type = 0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=64420   disable_nbt = DISABLED
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=64420 OpenVPN 2.4.6 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [PKCS11] [AEAD] built on Apr 26 2018
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=64420 Windows version 6.1 (Windows 7) 64bit
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=64420 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018, LZO 2.10
Enter Management Password:
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=65420 MANAGEMENT: TCP Socket listening on [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25341
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=65420 Need hold release from management interface, waiting...
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=533480 MANAGEMENT: Client connected from [AF_INET]127.0.0.1:25341
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=633993 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'state on'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=633993 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'log all on'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=724504 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'echo all on'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=725504 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'bytecount 5'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=726504 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold off'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=727504 MANAGEMENT: CMD 'hold release'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=727504 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=733005 LZO compression initializing
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=733005 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1622 D:1212 EF:38 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=733005 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1531262644,RESOLVE,,,,,,
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=767510 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1622 D:1450 EF:122 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=768010 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1570,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA256,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=768010 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1570,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA256,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=768010 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]209.6.118.XXX:1194
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=768010 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=768010 UDP link local: (not bound)
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=768010 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]209.6.118.XXX:1194
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=768010 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1531262644,WAIT,,,,,,
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=815516 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1531262644,AUTH,,,,,,
Tue Jul 10 18:44:04 2018 us=815516 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]209.6.118.XXX:1194, sid=e265c8c8 60047a33
Tue Jul 10 18:44:06 2018 us=680752 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=MA, L=Lexington, O=lmei, OU=tellyoulater, CN=GleasonVPN, name=dontwanttotellyou, emailAddress=XXX@yahoo.com
Tue Jul 10 18:44:06 2018 us=682253 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=MA, L=Lexington, O=lmei, OU=tellyoulater, CN=GleasonVPN, name=dontwanttotellyou, emailAddress=XXX@yahoo.com
Tue Jul 10 18:44:06 2018 us=844773 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 4096 bit RSA
Tue Jul 10 18:44:06 2018 us=844773 [GleasonVPN] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]209.6.118.XXX:1194
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=46926 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1531262648,GET_CONFIG,,,,,,
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=46926 SENT CONTROL [GleasonVPN]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=79930 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1625
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1553 D:1450 EF:53 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=80430 interactive service msg_channel=428
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=84431 ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.1.10.1/255.255.255.0 I=26 HWADDR=e8:2a:ea:22:78:65
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=104433 open_tun
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=106434 TAP-WIN32 device [Local Area Connection 3] opened: \\.\Global\{F573114C-0617-4F9D-9647-1ED45ED5ADC6}.tap
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=106934 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.21 
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=106934 TAP-Windows MTU=1500
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=108934 Set TAP-Windows TUN subnet mode network/local/netmask = 10.8.0.0/10.8.0.2/255.255.255.0 [SUCCEEDED]
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=108934 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.8.0.2/255.255.255.0 on interface {F573114C-0617-4F9D-9647-1ED45ED5ADC6} [DHCP-serv: 10.8.0.254, lease-time: 31536000]
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=109434 Successful ARP Flush on interface [32] {F573114C-0617-4F9D-9647-1ED45ED5ADC6}
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=112434 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Tue Jul 10 18:44:08 2018 us=112434 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1531262648,ASSIGN_IP,,10.8.0.2,,,,
Tue Jul 10 18:44:13 2018 us=319095 TEST ROUTES: 1/1 succeeded len=0 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Tue Jul 10 18:44:13 2018 us=319095 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 209.6.118.XXX MASK 255.255.255.255 10.1.10.1
Tue Jul 10 18:44:13 2018 us=323096 Route addition via service succeeded
Tue Jul 10 18:44:13 2018 us=323596 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.8.0.1
Tue Jul 10 18:44:13 2018 us=328097 Route addition via service succeeded
Tue Jul 10 18:44:13 2018 us=328097 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.8.0.1
Tue Jul 10 18:44:13 2018 us=330597 Route addition via service succeeded
Tue Jul 10 18:44:13 2018 us=330597 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Tue Jul 10 18:44:13 2018 us=330597 Initialization Sequence Completed
Tue Jul 10 18:44:13 2018 us=331097 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1531262653,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.8.0.2,209.6.118.XXX,1194,,
Tue Jul 10 18:48:32 2018 us=131960 PID_ERR replay-window backtrack occurred [4] [SSL-0] [0000_00377777777EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE] 0:435 0:431 t=1531262912[0] r=[0,64,15,4,1] sl=[13,64,64,528]
Tue Jul 10 18:58:52 2018 us=999801 PID_ERR replay-window backtrack occurred [37] [SSL-0] [0_____________________________________00000000000000000000000000] 0:6630 0:6593 t=1531263532[0] r=[-1,64,15,37,1] sl=[26,64,64,528]
```

Client Config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote XXX.hopto.org 1194
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 4
float
ca ca.crt
cert client1.crt
key client1.key
comp-lzo yes
tun-mtu 1500
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-CBC
redirect-gateway def1
```

[image]
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds more like a DNS problem than a routing issue - email client probably cached the server IP so that's why that works. If you try and access a website via IP does it work?

Comment: You are right. After I added the dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8, it works now.